# Does Ubuntu support for Intel Ultra 5 prosseccor?

Tags: touchpad, desktop-environments

I've bought a lenovo laptop, thinkbook 14 G6+ IMH.
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 5 125H   1.20 GHz

The problem is that I cannot install Ubuntu 22.04 or 23.10, result is "install failed", and also I found that the touchpad is unusable, only mouse can control the point.

Is there any detail I have ignored? And Is there solution?

Comment: Typically very new systems need the very latest kernel & drivers. And it takes some time before kernel is updated and then more time before all those changes are included into a distribution. Was it 22.04.3? Or you may need to wait for 24.04 which is not supported here yet as 24.04 not yet released. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Will Aim To Ship With The Linux 6.8 Kernel  rel in March as of update Jan 2024
https://www.phoronix.com/news/Ubuntu-24.04-Will-Use-Linux-6.8 You can try 24.04 but then are a tester and should not rely on it for daily use. Also: https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: thanks. I've tried 22.04.3, and it didn't work on. I'll concern on the processing of adapting. Thank you.